# setattr в классах python

Tags: python, классы

Пишу класс для работы с файлом конфигурации:

```
class Config():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = open(filename, "w")
        self.filename = filename

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        print attr, val
```

Проблема в том, что мне не нужно, чтобы отображались self.file и self.filename, а отображались только атрибуты, присвоенные классу после init.

Comment: Простите, отображались где?

Comment: Отображались в stdout.

Comment: Отображение объектов в текстовом виде можно задать в 
`object.__repr__(self)` [Objects, values and types](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Или попробуйте сформулировать вопрос по другом.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно так? Если да, то хэшкоду нужен штатный переводчик с языка начинающих ООПеров на русский -- просто изложить проблему простыми словами ребята не хотят. Я просто попытался догадаться по смыслу, поскольку описание класса от [@mrDoctorWho](/users/4772/mrdoctorwho) не позволяет открывать какой-либо файл (точнее открыть-то можно, а вот сохранить имя и хэндл открытого в аттрибутах -- нет)

```
class Config():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = open(filename, "w")
        self.filename = filename

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if not (attr in ('filename', 'file')): print attr, val
        self.__dict__[attr] = val
```

Comment: Мне не нужно было сохранять данные, это просто пример.

Comment: Вообще, я думал, что есть какой-то другой путь, кроме проверки имени attr

Comment: Если `__setattr__` на самом деле ничего не должен сохранять, то можно просто проверить: `if not attr in self.__dict__`

Правда в этом случае `__init__` в таком виде работать не будет, придется напрямую присваивать: self.__dict__['filename'] = filename

Comment: Т.е. что было нужно @mrDoctorWho мы так и не узнаем.

Answer (score 2):

Т.е. вы хотите сделать атрибуты file и filename приватными?

```
class Config():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__file = open(filename, "w")
        self.__filename = filename

obj = Config('/dev/null')

# AttributeError: Config instance has no attribute '__filename'
obj.__filename
```

Comment: Нет. Мне нужен специфический setattr для задания значений файла конфигурации с помощью атрибутов класса.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, я понял, чего в итоге хотят добиться:
Что есть сейчас:

```
>>> class Config(object):
...     def __init__(self, filename):
...         self.filename = filename
...     def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
...         print ("attr = '{}' val = '{}'".format(attr, val))
... 
>>> config = Config('file.txt')  # Не хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
attr = 'file.txt' val = 'xx'
>>> config.x = 1           # Хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
attr = 'x' val = '1'
>>>
```

Как я вижу рещение проблемы:

```
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class Private(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Config(object):
...     private = Private()
...     def __init__(self, filename):
...         self.private.filename = filename
...     def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
...         if attr not in vars(self.private):
...             print ("attr = '{}' val = '{}'".format(attr, val))
... 
>>> config = Config('file.txt')  # Не хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
>>> config.x = 1  # Хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
attr = 'x' val = '1'
>>>
```

На самом деле аналогичное решение предлагал @alexlz. 
Я просто немного обобщил.

Идея в том, что нужно просто вести список атрибутов, которые мы не хотим показывать при `__setattr__`. Сделать это можно по разному. Зависит от того, что в итоге хочется получить.

В моем примере `private` можно, например упростить, сказав, что 
`private = object()`. Или, еще прямолиненее, сдедать его словарем.

В данном случае, для  проверки как раз и используется всего лишь словарь, который возвращает функция `var()`.

На самом деле идею, можно развить еще дальше, и получить что-то типа.

```
>>> import six
>>> 
>>> class Private(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         self.private = self
...         for attr, value in six.iteritems(kwargs):
...             setattr(self, attr, value)
... 
>>> class Config(object):
...     private = Private(
...         mode = None
...     )
...     def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
...         self.private = Private(
...             filename=filename, 
...             **kwargs
...         )
...     def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
...         if attr not in vars(self.private):
...             print ("attr = '{}' val = '{}'".format(attr, val))
... 
>>> config = Config('file.log')  # Не хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
>>> 
>>> config = Config('file.log', mode='w')  # Не хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
>>> 
>>> config = Config('file.log', format='yaml')  # Не хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
>>> 
>>> config.x = 1  # Хотим чтобы тут что-то отображалось
attr = 'x' val = '1'
```

Только не очень понятно, зачем может потребоваться подобная функциональность.
Кроме того, разного рода действия с `__setattr__` потенциально опасны,
ибо например, могут выстреливать, при разного рода преобразованиях, сеарилизациях десериализациях, и делают код менее очевидным.

Comment: Четырехлетний некропост? Пожалуй, это рекорд.

Comment: @m9_psy А почему это плохо?

Comment: А я не говорил, что это плохо