# Знаки подчёркивания в переменных и методах

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js

Я работаю с python и javascript, и часто вижу в чужом коде переменные, функции или методы, которые начинаются с нижнего подчёркивания или обёрнуты в одно или два нижних подчёркивания. По какому принципу разработчики оборачивают некоторые методы, а некоторые оставляют без подчёркиваний, мне непонятно. Есть какие-то негласные правила такого оформления или я плохо читаю документацию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В питоне:

Если переменная начинается с одного подчёркивания (_name), то это переменная, предназначенная для использования только внутри объекта, внутри которого она объявлена. Её всё равно можно вызвать извне, написав object._name

Одинарное подчёркивание - это просто указание на то, что переменная относится к внутренней механике объекта и лучше её не трогать без лишней необходимости.

Если переменная начинается с двойного подчёркивания, но не имеет подчёркиваний в конце (__name), то эту переменную вы уже не сможете вызвать извне обычным способом object.__name

Впрочем, с помощью особого синтаксиса даже к ней можно подобраться извне, но делать это крайне не рекомендуется - уж если программист решил защитить переменную двойным подчёркиванием, то, наверное, у него были причины это сделать.

Имена, "обёрнутые" в двойные подчёркивания - это так называемые "магические" или "волшебные" методы. С их помощью реализуются некоторые специальные механики поведения объектов.

Answer (score 2):

В этих языках нет возможности сделать методы и свойства класса по-настоящему приватными, поэтому разработчики договорились добавлять к ним префиксы-андерскоры. Но в некоторых соглашениях это намеренно запрещёно, например, в [соглашении airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--leading-underscore).

Comment: Строго говоря вы не правы. При использовании определенного подхода к написанию кода это возможно. **В javascript** — если делать публичные методы класса на замыканиях, то для приватных объявлять локальные переменные в теле конструктора. И кажется, это достаточно распространненая практика в ES 5.
**В python**, это все можно организовать например, через магию c `__setattr__`, `__getattr__`, например, как-то так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81843/#551736
Либо обрабатывать методы по именам в метаклассе (в итоге тоже будет `__setattr__`, `__getattr__`). Но смысла в этом особого нет.

Comment: @Iliaw495Nikitin, да, в гайде airbnb именно об этом и написано. Скажем так: нет простого стандартного способа сделать приватные методы, в отличие от, например, Java. Кому-то хочется настоящей приватности и они заморачиваются с замыканиями, а кому-то достаточно пометить "приватные" сущности андерскором.